# Pandas: Selecting rows in a table

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, rows, selection

I am trying to select these rows (where T-stage = 3 AND N-stage = 0 AND Radiation = 1) from three columns (T-stage, N-stage, and Radiation) with Python from the Table below. I used the following but the results is not what was expected:

df=pd.read_csv('Mydata.csv') // Loading my data

#I tried the two approaches below, but the results were not what I expected.

A = ((df['T-stage'] == 3) | (df['N-stage'] == 0 | (df['Radiation'] == 1)))

or

B = ((df['T-stage'] == 3) & (df['N-stage'] == 0 & (df['Radiation'] == 1)))

[image: Mydata]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some `()` mismatch, for each condition use one `()`:

```
B = df[(df['T-stage'] == 3) & (df['N-stage'] == 0) & (df['Radiation'] == 1)]
```